# How to make a delay between Http request and Response on Apache server

Tags: apache

I have a method of request processing of web traffic. I use Modsecurity module on my apache server and i process the log of alerts of Modsecurity each time, and i want server to make a delay when it wants to response to any request when i am processing that logs of request.

I mean,i need an instruction to configure my apache server in order to make a specific delay to response to a request.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, there is no built-in way of making delay in apache. However there is some nice workaround. You can use filtering to busy your server with work and to make it respond slower.

There is mod_ext_filter module which takes server output/input and runs it through external application. If you read [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ext_filter.html) on this module, you'll find following example (add this to your httpd.conf):

```
# mod_ext_filter directive to define a filter
# which runs everything through cat; cat doesn't
# modify anything; it just introduces extra pathlength
# and consumes more resources
ExtFilterDefine slowdown mode=output cmd=/bin/cat \
    preservescontentlength


# core directive to cause the slowdown filter to
# be run several times on output
#
SetOutputFilter slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown;slowdown
```

What it does it just says mod_ext_filter to run cat many times on server output. It makes my server pretty slow. Don't forget to check that apache loads the mod_ext_filter (httpd.conf):

```
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
```

Comment: This works great for me. 
I just found another way I would like to share:
(This doesn't answer OP's question but solved my problem and thus might help others)
Set the "throttle" in Chrome's Dev Tools, under the Network tab.
Do like so: 
Open page in Chrome, right click and choose Inspect (or start the dev tools in some other way). Choose the Network Tab and at upper right click on the "No throttling" drop down and choose simulated network speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use filters to make the delay.
If urs is jsp based one,use servlet concept filters,
Try to slow the control inside dofilter() method

Comment: It is not a java based one. which filter would be suitable for it?